# Setters & Getters returning 0 value

Tags: java, constructor, super

For some reason when I input values for RTH and CTH I receive 0.0 values. I had a similar issue on my shift getters, but I managed to fix that. Unfortunately, attempting to reverse engineer the problem hasn't helped. I've provided the code for my class and my driver, although I am almost convinced the issue is somewhere in the class. Nevertheless, can anyone take a quick look at the RTH / CTH setters/ getters and see what I've done wrong in setting or calling them.

```
public class TeamLeader extends ProductionWorker
{
    //private variables

    private double RTH;
    private double CTH;
    private double payRate;
    private double monthlyBonus;

    //constructor
    public TeamLeader(String name, String number, String hd, int shift, 
            double rate, double monthlyBonus, double RTH, double CTH)
    {

    super(name, number, hd, shift, rate);
        this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;
    }


    public void setmonthlyBonus(double monthlyBonus)
    {
        this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;
    }

    public void setpayRate(double payRate)
    {
        this.payRate = payRate;
    }

    public void setRTH(double r)
    {
        RTH = r;
    }

    public void setCTH(double c)
    {
        CTH = c;
    }
    //Getters

    public double getmonthlyBonus()
    {
        return monthlyBonus;
    }

    public double getpayRate()
    {
        return payRate;
    }

    public double getRTH()
    {
        return RTH;
    }

    public double getCTH()
    {
        return CTH;
    }
}
```

Driver

```
   public class WorkDriver {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String name;
           String number;
           String hireDate;
           int shift;
           double payRate;
           double monthlyBonus;
           double RTH;
           double CTH;

           name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
           number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("Enter your number (Format: XXX-L)");
           hireDate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your hire date");
           shift = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("Please enter the work shift for the employee:\n"
                            + "\tEnter 1 for the day shift"
                            + "\n\tEnter 2 for the night shift"));
           payRate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("Enter your pay rate"));
           monthlyBonus = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("Enter your monthly bonus"));
           RTH = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("Enter your required traing hours"));
           CTH = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                            ("Enter your training hours attended"));

           //Production worker object
           TeamLeader driver = new TeamLeader(name, number,
                   hireDate, shift, payRate, monthlyBonus, RTH, CTH);

           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "----------- Employe Info ----------------"
                   + "\nName: " + driver.getName() 
                   + "\nEmployee Number: " + driver.getNumber() 
                   + "\nHire Date: " + driver.getHireDate() 
                   + "\nPay Rate: " + driver.getPayRate() 
                   + "\nShift: " + driver.getShift() 
                   + "\nMonthly Bonus: " + driver.getmonthlyBonus() 
                   + "\nRequired Training Hours: " + driver.getRTH() 
                   + "\nTraining Hours Attended: " + driver.getCTH());
           System.exit(0);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Your constructor takes an argument named RTH. Where does it store this argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call the setters of `CTH` and `RTH`. You pass their values to your constructor but don't use them.

Add to your constructor setting of `CTH` and `RTH` :

```
public TeamLeader(String name, String number, String hd, int shift, 
        double rate, double monthlyBonus, double RTH, double CTH)
{
    super(name, number, hd, shift, rate);
    this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;
    this.RTH = RTH;
    this.CTH = CTH;
}
```

Comment: Oh lord ... what a foolish mistake I don't know how I didn't realize that derp, you are correct and I shall award you the +1 when I can, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the parent (super) constructor, but it doesn't take RTH or CTH, and  you never set RTH and CTH on your TeamLeader object.

Answer (score 0):

```
      public TeamLeader(String name, String number, String hd, int shift, 
                double rate, double monthlyBonus, double RTH, double CTH)
        {

        super(name, number, hd, shift, rate);
            this.monthlyBonus = monthlyBonus;
            this.RTH = RTH;
            this.CTH = CTH;
        }
```

You are not setting the passed RTH to the instance's RTH. See code above for the fix